# Designing Django models for questions to have different answer types

Tags: django, django-models

I am create a survey app that I want to be fully dynamic the Quiz model will have many to many relationship with the Question model for a Survey can have multiple questions and the question can be used in multiple survey. My problem is the Answers model for questions. I want to allow different types of answers like (multiple choice or essay or whatever other type) but for each Quiz the question will have only one answer type thats related to it. what can I design that ?

Answer (score 1):

I think your answer is really broad, too broad in fact. But I will give a broad answer in the same vein as the question.

It seems pretty straight forward, you have a `many-to-many` with Question/Survey, so just model your `Question` and `Answer` in a related similar fashion.

> but for each Quiz the question will have only one answer type thats related to it.

I think you meant 'for each Question'... so build your `Answer` model in such a way that it can be of various types. Perhaps the relationship should be the standard `one-to-one`, depending how you build the `Answer` model... but it's hard to know.

This question is just too broad for a real answer that isn't just conjecture and/or theory.